# Mac: How to get a BSD block device name for a mount path

Tags: macos, bsd

I have a mount point path like "/Volumes/Something" which i already known is a root directory for a mounted local volume. I need to figure out the BSD block device node name for volume mounted at that directory for example "disk1s1". Any advice on how can i dig this up? I also wouldn't mind some additional information like device total size, but i already have a way to know it *if* i know a block device name.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `statfs` syscall. Look at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/statfs.2.html